# MP4 and MKV online video streaming

Tags: video, video-streaming, mp4

I want to know when i try to transfer a MP4 or MKV video, via online video streaming how does it transfer? i mean the packets of those video will still keep the formats of their specification or it will change?
(for example MP4 have [moov, mdat] format, does every packet in streaming have this format or the headers and the data will transfer apart?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer on your question may be very and very big and complicated, because it is important to begin from "what do you mean by streaming" ?  For example you may try to use something like MP4Box or ffmpeg than can segment your mp4 to segments in format suitable for DASH or HLS streaming.  Otherwise you can try to repack mp4 for such rare thing like "mp4 streaming" with moof atoms.

Comment: @MaxLapshin assuming that i want to stream a MP4 video file over RTP how do the segmention work here? the units are going to be as one segment?

Comment: if you want to stream mp4 over rtp, you have two options: use h264 -> rtp (RFC 3984) packetization + aac -> rtp (RFC 3640) OR  pack h264, aac to mpegts and use  mpegts -> rtp packetizaion.  In any case you need to extract frames from mp4, pack them to required transport and send.  With mpegts packetization you can just stream to multicast without RTSP.  If you are ready to use RTSP (for pause, rewind), then you can use separate h264/rtp and aac/rtp rtp packet streams.